# Store multiple values in one database field in Access (hear me out)

Tags: database, ms-access

So I've done extensive searching on this and I can't seem to find a good solution that actually applies to my situation.

I have a list of projects in a table, then a list of people. I want to assign multiple people to one project. Seems pretty common. Obviously, I can't make multiple columns on my projects table for each person, as the people will change fairly frequently.

I need to display this information very quickly in a continuous list of projects (the ultimate way would be a multiple-select combobox as a listbox is too tall, but they don't exist outside of the dreaded lookup fields)

I can think of two ways:
- Store multiple employee IDs delimited by commas in one field in my projects table (I know this goes against good database design). Would require some code to store and retrieve the data.
- Have a separate table for employees assigned to projects (ID, ProjectID, EmployeeID). One to many relationship between projects table and this new table. One to many relationship between employees table and this new table. If a project has 3 employees assigned, it would store 3 records in this table. It seems a bit odd joining both tables in this way, and would also require code to get it to store and retrieve into a control like the one mentioned above).

Does anyone know if there is a better way (including displaying in an easy control) or how you usually tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to tackle this problem would be with a Junction Table. This is what you describe where you have a separate table maybe called `EmployeeProject` which has an `EmployeeProjectID`(PK), `EmployeeID`(FK) and `ProjectID`(FK).

In this way you model a Many-to-Many relationship where each project can have many employees involved and each employee can be involved in many projects. It's not actually all that difficult to do the SQL etc. required to pull the information back together again for display.

I would definitely stay away from storing comma-delimited values as this becomes significantly more complicated when you want to display or manipulate the data.

There's a good guide here: http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/create-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-access but if you google "many to many junction table" or similar, there are thousands of pages/articles about implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you think it would be best to display this information in the continuous form I mentioned in the post? Listbox would be too tall, combobox doesn't allow for multiple inputs?

Comment: I'd most likely have a main form with a listbox or combobox with project ID in it, and a linked subform with a query as the recordsource. I'm unsure of the specifics of getting this to work without trying it - you might be able to get it to work by using "link child field" and "link master field" in the subform properties, or you might need to write a simple OnChange event for the ProjectID listbox such that it updates the recordsource of the subform.

Comment: I know I could get it to work with a subform or with a listbox on single record view, but for views where I have multiple projects listed down the page (like quite a lot) I need a VERY simple way of quickly assigning/unassigning people from projects. The most convenient method would be a combobox with multiple selection (like the multiple lookup feature in Access which I will never ever use) but that control doesn't exist on its own annoyingly. Not sure there is a solution for this

Comment: Do you want to see the list of all projects and assigned people in a single scrollable format?

Comment: Essentially, yes but editable. So the single scrollable format would be of the projects, and ideally one single control (that doesn't take up as much vertical space as a listbox) could edit the people assigned.

Comment: Essentially what you have there is an interface problem. I think you'd be best off posting that as a separate question.

Comment: Yeah I've decided to just display them on the continuous form and use a subform on the single record edit view for editing. Quick question (too short for a whole question on here): When Access links a form to a subform, does it alter the query that the subform is based on (if it is based on a query) or does it load the full query, then filter the records based on the linked field? just trying to think about when this database grows..

Comment: I don't know, and finding out seems to be difficult. Either way though I think the performance of running a new query or filtering the existing query should be fast whatever happens, so long as your fields are indexed properly etc. - the queries themselves will be quite simple and I doubt you'll be looking at millions of records(?).

Comment: There's a similar relationship structure in another part of the system where the number of rows in the association table may tip over a million in the next few years (I have started another question about it!). Ok cool, thanks for your help!