# Microsoft Access and storing multiple values in one field -how best to import from Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access

This is in line with an earlier stackoverflow question: [Store multiple values in one database field in Access (hear me out)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27377959/77335)

I have a Contacts database with a junction table ContactType which has a ContactTypeID (PK), ContactID (FK) and TypeID (FK).

Question is, I am importing the data from Excel. Is the following the best way to set up Excel for this?

In Excel have one row for each contact and several columns for the different type codes (i.e. each row will have 10 columns available for type codes). 
In Access create a Union Query that will take all the type codes in each row and make a Junction table with one or more records for each contact, each record consisting of contact and type.

Is there a better way to set up Excel for this data entry? It seems awkward although I've done it before and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Access Union queries have a limitation as well as the text of SQL. So if your data is large, this approach may not scale well.

One strategy you could do is running an Excel macro to loop through each row and transpose each row into same column to create the many-to-many Junction table import.

```
Sub NormalizeData()
    currlastrow = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To currlastrow
        newlastrow = Sheets(2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        'COPY/PASTE REPEATING CONTACT NAME
        Sheets(2).Range("A" & newlastrow + 1 & ":A" & newlastrow + 10) = Sheets(1).Range("A" & i)

        'COPYING DISTINCT TYPE CODES
        Sheets(1).Range("B" & i & ":K" & i).Copy

        'TRANSPOSING DISTINCT TYPE CODE
        Sheets(2).Range("B" & newlastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

        MsgBox newlastrow
    Next i
End Sub
```

Some cleanup of empty rows may be involved. But essentially, this is reshaping the data from wide to long format with your end result as a normalized m:m table.

WIDE FORMAT:

```
CONTACT   |  TYPE1 |  TYPE 2  |  TYPE 3 |  TYPE 4 |  TYPE 5 ...
Anna          Java     C++        SQL       PHP       Python    
Bob           VB       Java       C#        C++       R     
Charlie       PHP      Ruby       Perl      CSS       VB
```

LONG FORMAT:

```
Contact |  TYPE
Anna       Java
Anna       C++
Anna       SQL
Anna       PHP
Anna       Python
Bob        VB
Bob        Java
Bob        C#
Bob        C++
Bob        R
Charlie    PHP
Charlie    Ruby
Charlie    Perl
Charlie    CSS
Charlie    VB
```

Comment: I understand this approach - it calls for transposing rows of fields to columns in Excel before importing as a table into Access. I hope to be able to adapt the code and make it work. Many thanks for your answer!